# Book (and/or podcast) recommendations for providing a historical & cultural context for Sichuan?

Tags: china, book, ancient-china, travel, medieval-china

A couple friends and I plan on taking a tour in the southwestern region of China, specifically Sichuan & Yunan, around spring of next year. I find that it always makes the trip more engaging and enjoyable to get some historical and cultural contexts for the place beforehand.

Being ethnically one myself, I'm not completely ignorant of Chinese history and culture (though my friends will mostly be). But I'd still love to get some book and/or podcast recommendations that has this region as its primary focus.

I understand that it's often impractical to treat an entire region of China as if it were in a vacuum, (Shu Han will almost invariably be discussed in the context of the other two kingdoms of its time for instance), so that's not what I'm expecting. But if you know of any good media that at least places Sichuan (and this broader southwestern region of China in general) at the forefront of its discussions, whether they be in the context of history (any periods), culture, economy, travel/geography, etc., and can recommend them, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In terms of history of Sichuan, you wouldn't be wrong if you start with [**salt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_in_Chinese_history). A [*book*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2715.Salt) on that might be a good idea too, given the popularity of their cuisine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check that out!

Comment: This is a fairly subjective question - how will you select an authoritative answer?  H:SE isn't a good fit for questions that generate lots of opinions without a clear authoritative answer.